# std::atomic_store and std::atomic_exchange do not exchange

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

According to [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), `std::atomic_exchange` and `std::atomic_store` are equivalent to a thread-safe `std::swap`. But that's not the behavior that I'm getting with g++ or clang++.

[Problem live on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3f90e16a32f871e) (see below)

It prints this though:

```
std::atomic_store

a: 0x1ed2c30    0
b: 0x1ed2c50    1

a: 0x1ed2c50    1
b: 0x1ed2c50    1

std::atomic_exchange

a: 0x1ed2c50    0
b: 0x1ed2c30    1

a: 0x1ed2c30    1
b: 0x1ed2c30    1
```

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong? Have I misread the documentation?

#### Code Listing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "std::atomic_store\n\n";
        auto a = std::make_shared<int>(0);
        auto b = std::make_shared<int>(1);

        std::cout
        << "a: " << a.get() << '\t' << *a << '\n'
        << "b: " << b.get() << '\t' << *b << '\n' << std::endl;

        std::atomic_store(&a, b);

        std::cout
        << "a: " << a.get() << '\t' << *a << '\n'
        << "b: " << b.get() << '\t' << *b << '\n' << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::cout << "std::atomic_exchange\n\n";
        auto a = std::make_shared<int>(0);
        auto b = std::make_shared<int>(1);

        std::cout
        << "a: " << a.get() << '\t' << *a << '\n'
        << "b: " << b.get() << '\t' << *b << '\n' << std::endl;

        std::atomic_exchange(&a, b);

        std::cout
        << "a: " << a.get() << '\t' << *a << '\n'
        << "b: " << b.get() << '\t' << *b << '\n' << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'std::atomic_exchange(&a, b)' cannot change b

Comment: That makes sense, but is disappointing. How is that an exchange?

Comment: For you to get a good understanding of what you can expect from those std:: functions, I recommend you go one level deeper and check atomics functions on unix systems or Interlocked functions on Windows. The c++ std:: atomics are basically wrappers around those, but keep most of the semantics. And possibly, the documentation of the "raw" atomic functions is less misleading.

Comment: @caps: It's an exchange in that you pass in `b` and get back the original `a` while atomically setting `a` to `b`. It's not exchanging `a` with `b` symmetrically, it's atomically extracting `a` in "exchange" for a new value, `b`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That description is somewhat misleading.

It says, e.g.,

```
template<class T>
void atomic_store( std::shared_ptr<T>* p,
                   std::shared_ptr<T> r );
```

"effectively" does `p->swap(r)`. Which is true as far as it gets (and is actually what the standard says, too).

But, `r` is a function argument passed by value, and so is destroyed before the function returns. It doesn't affect anything in the caller.

Comment: Yes, I see I should have "read between the lines" by paying more attention to the parameter types.

Comment: What is the advantage of having this helper method if the same can be accomplished by same one liner via ```std::atomic<T>::exchange``` ?

Answer (score 3):

`std::atomic_exchange` does not swap a and b, it sets a to b and returns the previous value of a.

You could do :

```
b = std::atomic_exchange(&a, b);
```

This would work as you expect (exchange the pointers of a and b) but this is not thread safe : if multiple threads access the object `b` at the same time, this is undefined behavior. You cannot do better since a shared pointer is a complex struct containing typically two data members (two pointers). As atomic lock-free exchange requires hardware support, this only works with basic types (integers, and pointers).

Comment: Is `reset` atomic/thread-safe? If not, then no, it would not work as I expect.

Comment: That wouldn't actually be an atomic swap though. You would have an indeterminate period where both `a` and `b` could have the same value.

Comment: Exactly. I may decide this is not an issue, but that's definitely not the same thing as an atomic/thread-safe swap, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, for a true atomic swap you need a loop which will check that the initial value of b did not change. I'm not good enough to write one here being 100% sure it will work but there are ways. You need a compare exchange instruction.

Comment: And what happens if the initial value changed?

Comment: There is no way to perform a true lock-less swap.

Comment: True, that's what I meant by a loop

Comment: A shared pointer is a complex structure involving a counter (int) and a pointer, there is no way a single instruction could swap this.

Comment: `b.reset(std::atomic_exchange(&a, b));` does not actually compile. Check the parameters for reset.

Comment: Yes, exchange returns a shared pointer and not a raw pointer. You need the assignment operator.

Comment: Assignment operator is not necessarily thread-safe. See my answer.

Comment: Off course, changing the value of a std::shared_ptr instance from different threads is not safe. But changing the value of different std::shared_ptr instances from different threads is safe even if they point to the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

It has been puzzling me for ages why 'compare-and-swap' has `swap` in it. It does not swap anything. It sets the value if check passess, and returns the current value if the check fails. So by no means atomic_exchange is any equivalent to std::swap.

Instead, it's a check-and-set pattern, so I always prefer CAS to mean compare-and-set.

Comment: Right, `atomic_exchange` is more similar to `std::exchange` IINM.

Comment: The functions in the docs referenced aren't the CAS routines, it's `atomic_exchange`, and cppreference is explicitly claiming equivalence (for `shared_ptr`) to `p->swap(r)`. Are they wrong? CAS is not relevant here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I misread the question, I admit. I thought OP was talking about `atomic_compare_exchange_*` routines.

Comment: @Morwenn, that's unsurprising given that `std::exchange` was proposed to be the non-atomic version of the `std::atomic_exchange` operation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the closest thing to the behavior I want is this:

```
    std::atomic_store(
        &b,
        std::atomic_exchange(
            &a,
            b
        )
    );
```

However, this is not strictly atomic. `a` and `b` could point to the same address for a fraction of a second.

In my case, that behavior is acceptable as long as they both point to valid, well-defined objects at all times.

Comment: You can't even atomically swap two scalar values on many processor architectures (it requires a ["double-compare-and-swap"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap) instruction, which is not widely available). However, since the atomic operations on `shared_ptr` are just implemented with a mutex in all implementations I know of, it would be possible to provide an `atomic_swap(`shared_ptr<T>&, shared_ptr<T>&)` (even though it couldn't be provided for `std::atomic`, not for the proposed `std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr` which doesn't use a mutex).